# Using the same File Output Stream in GUIs

Tags: javafx, filestream

I need to continue writing to the same file using a file output stream, However I'm implementing the program using a javafx GUI from different windows. but:

- Since you can not access a global variable without intializing the stream as final I have to make it final however,
- Since I have to wrap the the Stream in a try catch, the variable is not recognised as initialised.

I was previously intialising in method like this

eW = outputFactory                                              .createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream("File.txt"));

However, that obivously overwrites the same file when you write the same statement again.

So essentially my question is, how can you set a final variable that needs to be surrounded in a try catch?

final File file =  new File("File.txt");
                final FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: Is there anyway I can bypass a try-catch?

Answer (score 1):

- You *don't* need to initialize a variable as final to access it from different threads or objects. There are other ways to do it.
- You can use a helper class, or even a helper thread. The second option is better in (the most common) case where you have more than 1 thread in your project. You can then use a normal `try-catch` block that has a (almost infinite) while loop inside, that checks a write queue and writes something when needed.
- If you only use 1 thread and only append to a file, you may want to do just that - open the file to append, rather than overwrite. There's a `boolean` flag in the constructor.

Comment: Hi, 
I can't upvote your comment becaue I'm a noob, but thanks for the answer.

how would you create a thread to use for a stream?

Comment: @GaryCassar Eh, just like any other thread? Make a globally accessible object that has a `Thread` inside it, along with a `BlockingQueue<String>` with a method to initialize it (to be run once), a method to add a `String` to the queue and a method to stop the thread (NOT by `stop()` or other nonsense like that, but properly). The run method would then contain a `try-catch` block with a `while (!done)` that reads from the queue and writes to the file. This is widely used in *Asynchronous Logging* in things like Log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-) constructor, which would allow you to append to the end of the file rather than overwrite each time.

I do not know how you implemented it, but if you are writing to the same file from multiple windows, it might be easier to have a helper class which exclusively handles writing to file. This would allow you to centralize your File output code to one place making it easier to debug and maintain.